# Braeintree Client Set Up with JS v3 - payment_method_nonce null and the form isn't submitting

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, braintree

I've tried to integrate Braintree in my Laravel 5.2 app and everything works fine with JS v2 client setup, but I would like to upgrade it to v3.
This is from the docs (I've customized a bit):

```
<form id="checkout-form" action="/checkout" method="post">
  <div id="error-message"></div>

  <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
  <div class="hosted-field" id="card-number"></div>

  <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
  <div class="hosted-field" id="cvv"></div>

  <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
  <div class="hosted-field" id="expiration-date"></div>

  <input type="hidden" name="payment-method-nonce">
  <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>

<!-- Load the Client component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.0.0-beta.8/js/client.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the Hosted Fields component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.0.0-beta.8/js/hosted-fields.min.js"></script>

<script>

var authorization = '{{ $clientToken }}'

braintree.client.create({
  authorization: authorization
}, function (clientErr, clientInstance) {
  if (clientErr) {
    // Handle error in client creation
    return;
  }

  braintree.hostedFields.create({
    client: clientInstance,
    styles: {
      'input': {
        'font-size': '14pt'
      },
      'input.invalid': {
        'color': 'red'
      },
      'input.valid': {
        'color': 'green'
      }
    },
    fields: {
      number: {
        selector: '#card-number',
        placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
      },
      cvv: {
        selector: '#cvv',
        placeholder: '123'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        selector: '#expiration-date',
        placeholder: '10 / 2019'
      }
    }
  }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {
    if (hostedFieldsErr) {
      // Handle error in Hosted Fields creation
      return;
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
        if (tokenizeErr) {
          // Handle error in Hosted Fields tokenization
          return;
        }

        document.querySelector('input[name="payment-method-nonce"]').value = payload.nonce;
        form.submit();
      });
    }, false);
  });
});
</script>
```

But when I click the submit button, nothing happens.`event.preventDefault()` stops the submission and the `payment_method_nonce` token is generated, but I can't submit the form after that, because `form.submit()` isn't works

How can I submit the form after `event.preventDefault()`?
Or how can I send the `payment_method_nonce` token to my controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied your snippet and tried to run the example, I got `(index):69 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined` in the console. When I added

```
var form = document.getElementById('checkout-form');
```

it worked just fine.

Best guess, you just forgot to assign the form variable to reference the form dom element. If that's not the case, be sure to let me know.